# Displaying some multiples

Tags: java, beginner, programming-challenge

[Displaying Some Multiples](http://programmingbydoing.com/a/displaying-some-multiples.html)

> Write a program to calculate the multiples of a given number. Have the user enter a number, and then use a for loop to display all the multiples of that number from 1 to 12. It is not necessary to use a function.
> You must use a for loop.

```
/*
 * Code by Clint <https://github.com/clieg>
 *
 *
 * Problem from: http://programmingbydoing.com/a/displaying-some-multiples.html
 */

import java.util.Scanner;

public class DisplayingSomeMultiples {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number;

        System.out.print("Choose a number: ");
        number = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
            int mutiply = number * i;
            System.out.println(number + " x " + i + " = " + mutiply);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `multiple` instead of `mutiply` will get you one point more. ;)

Comment: @JoopEggen or removing the temporary variable entirely...

Comment: Strictly speaking, your program outputs much more then what it is supposed to ;)

Answer (score 3):

That looks quite good actually, minor stuff only.

---

```java
for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
```

I'm a persistent advocate for using "real" names for loop variables, like `index` or `count` or `factor` in this case.

```java
        for (int factor = 1; factor <= 12; factor++) {
            int result = number * factor;
            System.out.println(number + " x " + factor + " = " + result);
        }
```

---

```java
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number;
```

Do not declare all variables at the beginning of the method, declare them only when needed, that will limit the variable from creeping into scopes they don't belong in.

---

You could define the maximum factor as a constant.